# How can I see full 3rd level profiles on LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin

My friends LinkedIn account (which is not a paid account) shows full profiles for 3rd level connections including who they are connected to that is 2nd level to the profile:

[image]

Whereas, I only see an overview of [their profile](https://www.linkedin.com/in/claudia-madrazo-31128234) with no mention of how I am connected:

[image]

How can I get the more indepth view without buying a subscription at LinkedIn and keeping my account free?  Could this relate to cookies that need to be deleted?  Both of us are using Chrome browser, my friend can even log in using my computer and see the more in-depth profiles with first leg of how the connection is made.  I also notice that when I logout, I get a different resulting logout page rendering than my friend.